# check out / check in tracked as a an edit

Tags: versioning

Is the act of checking out and checking in a document considered an edit?  We are trying to determine if someone was in fact editing a document or just opening and looking at a document.  We did not have track changes set up in Word for the document.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean in Audit log? if so they are different events. 
REF: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/view-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131

if you had audit log was enabled you should be able to differentiate.

if you had versioning on you could compare existing version to the previous one.